# Scala: What is making this algorithm for Collatz Sequences so inefficient?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, visualvm

I'm trying to solve a variation of the [collatz problem on project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14):

> n → n/2 (n is even)
>
> n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)
>
> Using the rule above and starting with 13, we generate the following
>   sequence:
>
> 13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1

My attempt is to find **the longest Collatz sequence for a number less than 
1 million**

To do that I wrote a brute force solution in Scala and optimized it.

While the optimized version solves the problem very quickly and efficiently, the brute force solution never completed eventually resulting in an out of memory error:

```
object LongestCollatz {
  def apply(upperbound: Long) = {
    bruteForce(upperbound)
  }

  def bruteForce(upperBound: Long) = (1l to upperBound)
    .map(toCollatzSequence)
    .map(list => list.length)
    .max

  def toCollatzSequence(start: Long): ListBuffer[Long] = {
    var term = start
    var retList = ListBuffer(start)
    if(start<=1) return retList
    while(term > 1) {
      if(term % 2 == 0) {
        term = term/2l
      } else {
        term = (3l * term) + 1
      }

      retList.addOne(term)
    }
    retList.addOne(1l)
    retList
  }
}

object Solver extends App {
  println("sol is " + LongestCollatz(1000000))
}
```

With visualvm and some logging I was seeing that each step of the range stream in the bruteforce method would complete entirely for all 1M numbers before moving onto the next step. So:
`.map(toCollatzSequence)`
was loading up the sequence for all 1M terms and keeping them in the heap until it could arrive at the next `.map()` statement to turn them into single-number lengths. I was able to fix that problem by revising the function:

```
  def bruteForce(upperBound: Long) = (1l to upperBound)
    .map(l => toCollatzSequence(l).length)
    .max
```

so consolidating the two map statements into one. My question, did I make an error by separating out the two maps? Or is a functional solution not a good idea in general for this type of problem?

Comment: I'm not a scala programmer, but generally in FP you compose the functions and pass *that* to map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `.view` to convert it to a non-strict collection.

You avoided an immediate list by fusing the two `.map`s into one, but the list of lengths is also avoidable when you are just calling `.max`.

```
def bruteForce(upperBound: Long) = (1l to upperBound)
  .view
  .map(toCollatzSequence)
  .map(_.length)
  .max
```

This should do the trick for a brute force solution.

Comment: George- I never knew this about `view` and enforcing lazy processing. I always thought streams were lazy by default so this was news to me. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 3):

> did I make an error by separating out the two maps?

It's seldom a good idea to sequence multiple `.map()` calls. Combining them will reduce the number of times you traverse the collection.

> is a functional solution not a good idea in general for this type of problem?

I don't know why you say that. What's *not* a good idea is to stop after coming up with a brute force solution. Brute force is just a starting point.

Here's a solution that uses tail recursion, lazy evaluation, and no mutable data.

```scala
@annotation.tailrec
def getLen(n: Long, count: Int = 0): Int =
  if (n < 2) count + 1
  else getLen(if (n % 2 == 0) n / 2 else 3 * n + 1, count + 1)

LazyList.tabulate(1000000)(n => (getLen(n),n)).max._2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as I indicated in my question I developed the optimized solution after the brute force and was mostly looking for information about how Scala processes streams